# php regex exclude string in url

Tags: php, css, regex

I have a regular expression

```
\(\'?.*(\/public\/images.*[^\'"])\'?\)
```

It matches ulrs in my CSS file.
Here is examples:

1. background: url(**/public/images/new_layout/bg-nav-active.png**) no-repeat 100% 100%;
2. background: url(**/public/images/new_layout/bg-nav-active.png?v=23423h423lj4h23l4jk23hl4jkh4h2kljh**) no-repeat 0 -

But, how to exclude parameter v from URL **?v=23423h423lj4h23l4jk23hl4jkh4h2kljh**

Thank You for help.

Comment: What you mean by exclude? You mean second case, It should not return in the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should suffice;

```
\(\'?.*(\/public\/images[^\'"\?\)]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/eZ7iO9/1

This will match the string "/public/images/" and everything that isn't in the character `'"?)`

Answer (score 1):

This regex will match just the URLs, without any parentheses or `?v`s due to the a lookbehind and a lookahead:

```
 (?<!\()['"]?.*(\/public\/images[^'"\?\)]+)
```

The non-greedy `.+?` makes it possible not to match `?v`s.

See [example here](https://regex101.com/r/oK1fP8/4).

The output of your 2 input strings is:

```
/public/images/new_layout/bg-nav-active.png
/public/images/new_layout/bg-nav-active.png
```

Comment: This may capture closing quotes.

Comment: Now, it won't capture closing quotes.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Who would be using inconsistent quotation marks like in `background: url('/public/images/new_layout/bg-nav-active.png")`?

Comment: .. even without inconsistent quotation marks: https://regex101.com/r/oK1fP8/2 (I rushed the fiddle, hence the inconsistency). You need to add `"` in your character class to not match `[^]`.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ: Agreed. It is the OP that misled me, since only single quotes are allowed in the beginning. I added the `['"]` character class to also allow double quotes.

Answer (score -2):

```
str_replace('v=', '', $string)
```